How to create a blinking effect in JavaFX using CSS?
I need a solution to create a blinking effect using only CSS. As I found out CSS transitions were added in JavaFX 23 (link). However, I couldn't create blinking using it. This is my code:
public class JavaFxTest10 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var label = new Label("Hello, world!");
        label.setStyle("visibility:visible; transition-property: visibility; transition-duration: 0.5s;");

        VBox root = new VBox(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Blinking Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Could anyone say how to do it, if it is possible?

This new feature is for "transitions" not "animations", which is pretty much going to mean the addition/removal of PseudoClasses to a CSS selector. So you cannot do what you're looking for entirely in CSS. However, you could create a PseudoClass and toggle it on/off in code - and you can detect the running transition ending and use that to trigger the PseudoClass toggle. This means that you could perform the animation with very minimal code - but not zero code.

There's enough code in this article I wrote to imagine how this would work. https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/css-transitions

Remember that users despise blinking.  So much so, the <blink> element was removed from the HTML specification, and most if not all browsers refuse to support blinking, whether specified as an element or as CSS.  Blinking should only be used for dire conditions, like “Your server’s internal temperature is 110°C and it is likely to catch fire.”

@VGR I have a section in my article about the dangers of doing too much obvious transition stuff: https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/css-transitions#some-thoughs-on-transitions .  There's a fine line between slick and professional looking and something that looks like a 1990's website built by a kid.

@DaveB Yes, I know that it is about transitions but the issue about animation was closed (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092084) saying it is related to transitions (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8311895)

@Stefman1987 JDK-8311895 lists CSS Animations as a "non-goal".  Down at the bottom, CSS Animations are listed as a "possible future enhancement".  For what it's worth, one of the other enhancements listed - the one about background elements - has been included int JFX-24.  So it's very possible that the CSS Animations will happen sooner rather than later.  But for now, the answer is "NO".

@DaveB As I understand closing CSS animation issue and marked it as "non-goal" means that in the nearest 10-100 years they won't implement it. But you say So it's very possible that the CSS Animations will happen sooner rather than later. Why do you think so? Could you explain?

+1 for the excellent article by @DaveB. That article pretty much covers the full details to understand the CSS transitions functionality.
So If you implement what @DaveB mentioned in his comment, it will be as below.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.css.TransitionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFxTest10 extends Application {
    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
                    .myLabel{
                       -fx-font-size:20px;
                       -fx-opacity: 1;
                       transition: -fx-opacity 200ms ease;
                    }
                                        
                    .myLabel:blink{
                        -fx-opacity: 0;
                    }
                    """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var blink = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("blink");
        var label = new Label("Hello, world!");
        label.getStyleClass().add("myLabel");
        label.addEventHandler(TransitionEvent.END, event -> label.pseudoClassStateChanged(blink, !label.getPseudoClassStates().contains(blink)));

        VBox root = new VBox(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Blinking Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> label.pseudoClassStateChanged(blink, true));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

